# PIMPL idiom accessibility issue

Tags: c++, access-modifiers, pimpl-idiom

I've implemented my class, lets say class `A` using standard PIMPL idiom. 
Problem arises when i try overloading `<<` operator for my implementation class `AImpl`

```
/* A.h */
class A {
public:
     ...
private:
     class AImpl;
     AImpl *impl;
}
/* Aimpl.h */
class AImpl {
     ...
     friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const AImpl &impl);
     ...
}
/* elsewhere.cpp */
ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const AImpl &impl) {
     ...
}
```

Problem stems from overloaded operator not having access to `AImpl` class, declared private in `A`.
Now i'm in sort of a dilemma over how i should resolve this. One way is declaring overloaded operator friend of class `A` too. The other way is making private declaration of class `AImpl` public.
Which approach is better and safer?

Comment: Yes another way is to define `operator<<` inside `AImpl`, instead of just declaring it.  More often than not with pImpl, the "Impl" class is best placed in "A.cpp" anyway, and there's little benefit and considerable verbosity from keeping the declarations and definitions separate.

Comment: Is this for serialization or printing? Usually, you don't want to print private parts of your class, so you need only a operator<< for A, which doesn't even have to be a friend.

Comment: How/why do you have access to {{AImpl}} anywhere else than {{A.cpp}} anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you're misusing the PIMPL idiom. The idiom calls for the implementation to be really private, that is `AImpl` should not be defined in a header file (for everyone to see), rather it should probably be defined in `A.cpp` where also the `<<` operator belongs.

If you do that the `<<` operator is pointless to declare in header file as well, the only way you would access the PIMPL would be via the containing class anyway. You would define `ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const A &obj)` instead and make that a `friend` of `A`.

Note that with this approach the `AImpl` does not need to be as restrictive about access. It's field and size would only be available from `A.cpp` anyway. But if you want to make the internals of `AImpl` be `private` you could make `ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const A &obj)` a `fried` of `AImpl` as well.

```
/* A.h */
class A {
public:
     ...
private:
     class AImpl;
     AImpl *impl;

     friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const A &obj);
}

/* A.cpp */
class AImpl {
public:
     // OR:
     friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const A &obj);

     ...
}

ostream &operator <<(ostream &os, const A &obj) {
     AImpl* impl = obj.impl;
     ...
}
```

Comment: I apologize, for not formulating my problem clearly enough. I wanted to overload `<<` operator for both `A` and `AImpl` so i could define operator for `A` using operator for `AImpl`. Also I neglected to mention that *AImpl.h* was a private header and not a public one, so I don't think i'm misusing PIMPL. 

However, the best solution appears to be overloading only the operator for main class, which i figured out about 10 minutes after posting this question. Which appears to be your solution too.

Comment: @Kijan You can still do that, but as `AImpl.h` is private (only for `A.cpp` to use) the contents of the header file would rather belong in `A.cpp`). The operator for `AImpl` should probably not need to access `A`: normally the pipml doesn't have any reference to the containing object and therefore there's no `A` object on which `AImpl::operator<<` would desire to operate on.